# Update Integrated in Build during build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I have linked work items to commits and I have added a build YAML pipeline. This build pipeline correctly links work items to the build by creating an 'Integrated in build' link such as the following:
[image]

However, the 'Integrated in Build' field remains blank. I would have expected this to be filled-in automatically but this is not happening. Do I need to do anything else for this field to be filled in?

My end goal is to be able to create a query where I can list all work items by 'Integrated in Build'. This would be easy if the 'Integrated in Build' was filled in. I also tried to use the 'Integrated in build' **link type** for this, but it seems that 'Integrated in Build' is not available in the query editor:
[image]

Comment: Hi, you mentioned "This build pipeline correctly links work items to the build by creating an 'Integrated in build' link such as the following:". I don't see this happening automatically through my build pipeline. Is there anything specific I have to do in the Azure DevOps build pipeline for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My end goal is to be able to create a query where I can list all work
>   items by 'Integrated in Build'.

For this issue , I am afraid this is currently unachievable in azure devops. The `Integrated in Build` in Development is not a `field`, but `Relations`. So it is not feasible to query based on `Integrated in Build` field.

Secondly, the query that can be performed according to link types is for **Related work** and not applicable to **Development**. So you can't find `Integrated in build` link type.

> However, the 'Integrated in Build' field remains blank. I would have
>   expected this to be filled-in automatically but this is not happening.

For this issue , the `Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild` field can not be used to get the build links for azure devops , since the `Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild` field is designed for the XAML build (not vNext build). And you can also find relation information in the blog [Automatic linking work items to builds](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/automatic-linking-work-items-to-builds/): The build fields are populated with build numbers only for XML builds. This will continue to work as is for XML builds. The new build system does not populate these fields.

Here is the [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/480314/integrated-in-build-field-does-not-update-on-work.html) with similar issue ,please refer to it.

Apart from the negative answer, I think what you want is a good idea! So I post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/949925/list-related-work-items-according-to-integrated-in.html) in DC forum. You could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there.The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Anyone interested in this can also vote for it and track it. Hope all above makes some help.

Comment: Thanks, as a workaround, I managed to use an extension - titled 'Work Item Updater' to update the Integrated In Build field

Comment: I see that this issue has been closed as "not a bug" in the forum. So, I can't even vote now. What do you suggest?